# Establish connection through multiple hops

Tags: networking, nat

I have a set-up as shown in this figure.
[set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoWfZ.png)
How do I establish connection(TCP,Ping etc...) between Laptop-1 and laptop-4. I have background in physical layer of wireless, but not much aware of networks :), nonetheless, I tried my best by searching on internet. Here are some more info:

IP forwarding is enabled on all the machines.
Operating system is Ubuntu 18.04.
There is no other device(switch/router etc) involved.
Subnet of 192.168.10.x is same but different from subnet of 10.0.0.x
A snapshot of the routing tables(after modified by me) of the machines is also here.
[routing-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTzQw.png)

Still I am not able to ping from 192.168.10.3 to 192.168.10.5

Please suggest what shall I do.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using the same subnet address on two different networks. For example, you should make one 192.168.10.0/24 and the other 192.168.11.0/24 or something else – *not* the same /16 on both. This will simplify things.

---

Take a look at your hosts' (Laptop-1 and Laptop-4) routing tables and note that neither of them actually has a route to the other host through your gateways.

The only matching route they have is a *local* route indicating that the destination (the entire 192.168.0.0/16 subnet in your case) is reachable on-link. (The route has no `G` flag, so it only specifies a local interface.)

This causes Laptop-1 to directly send layer-2 ARP queries attempting to learn Laptop-4's MAC address – but **there is no device** which would respond to them, as Laptop-4 is on a physically separate network (and therefore won't receive the ARP query), and Desktop-2 will not respond because it doesn't own the requested IP address.

(This behavior is normal when accessing hosts that are "within the same subnet". Indeed, that's what being within the same subnet *means*, and that's why I recommend that you avoid using identical subnet addresses in different places.)

---

So in your case, it is not enough to add the routes on gateways – you need to tell the hosts themselves which layer-2 device to send the packets to.

There are two ways to deal with this situation – choose one *or* the other, not all of them:

- Option 1: The same 192.168.1.x routes that you have on Desktop-2 also need to be added on Laptop-1 (but with "192.168.10.2" i.e. Desktop-2 as the gateway, of course). Likewise, the two routes on Desktop-3 have to be copied to Laptop-4.

  As they have a longer prefix length (/32), those routes will automatically have priority over the /16 subnet route.
- Option 2: The gateways need to have the Proxy-ARP feature enabled on eno1, so that they *would* respond to the ARP queries on behalf of hosts which are not here. For example, Desktop-2 would respond to ARP on behalf of 192.168.10.5.

Comment: many thanks, with your suggestions, I'm able to ping between laptop-1 and laptop-4, however ssh does not work. It says no route to host. Can you please guide. I followed the option-1.

Comment: Laptop-1: 192.168.11.3; Desktop-2: 192.168.11.2(eno1),10.187.88.98(wlp110so); Laptop-4: 192.168.10.5; Desktop-3: 192.168.10.1(eno1),10.187.88.107(wlp110so). I can ssh between laptop-1 and desktop-2 as ssh ubadmin@192.168.11.2 and same between laptop-4 and desktop-3 as ssh ubadmin@192.168.10.1. But cannnot ssh between laptop-1 and laptop-4.

Comment: Have you looked at a packet capture to check what's happening? (That's one of the first things to do.) In general, both ping and SSH to the same destination should behave identically, as routing tables don't distinguish protocols – so I would suspect that your routing is fine but the error message is caused by a firewall somewhere.

Comment: Ok I checked the trace while doing ssh from 192.168.11.3 to 192.168.10.5. This goes via the gateway 192.168.11.2. but 192.168.11.2 replies to 192.168.11.3: Destination Unreachable(Host administratively prohibited).

Comment: One more comment: I can ssh hop-by-hop ,i.e., laptop-4 to desktop-3, then desktop-3 to desktop-2 and then desktop-2 to laptop-1...but not directly from laptop-4 to laptop-1.

Comment: "Administratively prohibited" means .11.2 is blocking it via firewall.

Comment: Yes you were right. So I did the following as it works now, many thanks.

Comment: sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-interface=wlp110s0, sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-interface=eno1 on Desktop-2 and Desktop-3.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not have enough reputation to vote your answer up :(

Comment: Can I ask one more question here: When I do iperf between Desktop-2 and 3, the throughput is approx 11 mbps but the iperf between laptop-1 and 2 never exceeds 10 mbps. What could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I followed option-1 as suggested by user1686 and then in Desktop-2 and Desktop-3 I did the following to make ssh work:

sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-interface=wlp110s0

sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-interface=eno1